# Marking associated object for destruction not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

The docs show this is how you mark and associated object for destruction but it's not working. How come?

The docs are at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html
showing:

```
member.avatar_attributes = { :id => '2', :_destroy => '1' }
member.avatar.marked_for_destruction? # => true
member.save
member.reload.avatar # => nil
```

I have:

appointment.rb

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :time_block
end
```

time_block.rb

```
class TimeBlock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :appointment
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointment, :allow_destroy => :true, 
                                              :reject_if => :all_blank

end
```

---

```
(rdb:144) @time_block.appointment_attributes = {"_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"48"}

(rdb:144) p @time_block.appointment.marked_for_destruction?
false
```

Comment: I think you need `has_one :appointment` in your TimeBlock model

Comment: O have that, sorry, forgot to include it. Updating post.

Answer (score 3):

`mark_for_destruction` only works if you add `autosave: true` to your model.

So change time_block.rb to use:

`has_one :appointment, autosave: 'true'`

For more info, see https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation/mark_for_destruction.

> Only useful if the :autosave option on the parent is enabled for this associated model.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the appointments to be destroyed when the TimeBlock is destroyed, include:

```
has_one :appointment, :dependent => :destroy
```

For more, see: [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: No, I want the appointment association to be destroyed when appointment_attributes has _destroy => true/1